# How to carve a square using Ctrl+I?

Tags: modeling

I've been following this tutorial trying to create this lamp post:

[image: Lamp Post]

And I'm having trouble doing the carved in square part in the center. In the video, he just does ctrl+i and scales it in. I have tried that but I can only scale in the top part:

[image: My Lamp Post]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

1. select a loop of faces
2. press <kbd>I</kbd>
3. press again <kbd>I</kbd>
4. scale by moving the mouse towards the center of your object
5. Click  <kbd>LMB</kbd>  (*left mouse button*)
6. press  <kbd>E</kbd>  do not move the mouse, I immediately
7. press  <kbd>S</kbd>  and now scale to the desired size
8. Click  <kbd>LMB</kbd>  (*left mouse button*) to end the action

[image: Inset Example]

### NOTE

- <kbd>I</kbd>  (inset) x 1, with only one face selected, it will
  create a single frame on that face
- <kbd>I</kbd>  (inset) x 1, with a loop of Selected faces will create a single frame on that face within the range of selected faces
- <kbd>I</kbd>  (inset) x 2, with a single face selected will create a single frame within each face of the selected range

[image: Inset + Inset Example]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> is to invert the selection, not inset. If you want to inset individual faces, don't just use <kbd>i</kbd>, use <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>, it should work.